# How to set a boolean flag from a component to another in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-components

I have 2 containers within a component's html, I'm trying to set which container to show upon click from my side menu component. I have tried using a service to set the boolean flag on click in my side menu component and then retrieve it from the service on another component but it's not working.

This is my `side-menu.component.html`:

```
<li>
  <a href="#accountPayableSubMenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Account Payable</a>
  <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="accountPayableSubMenu">

    <li>
      <a [routerLink]="['./account-payable']" (click)="onCreateAccountPayableClick()">Create Account Payable</a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a [routerLink]="['./account-payable']" (click)="onViewAccountPayableClick()">View Account Payable</a>
    </li>

  </ul>
</li>
```

This is my `side-menu.component.ts`:

```
export class SideMenuComponent implements OnInit {
  accountPayableService: AccountPayableService;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  onCreateAccountPayableClick() {
    this.accountPayableService.createAccountPayableClick = true;
    this.accountPayableService.viewAccountPayableClick = false;
  }

  onViewAccountPayableClick() {
    this.accountPayableService.createAccountPayableClick = false;
    this.accountPayableService.viewAccountPayableClick = true;
  }
}
```

and my `account-payable.service.ts`:

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class AccountPayableService {
  createAccountPayableFlag = this.createAccountPayableClick;
  viewAccountPayableFlag = this.viewAccountPayableClick;

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    public createAccountPayableClick: boolean = false,
    public viewAccountPayableClick: boolean = false
  ) {}

}
```

and I have this in my `account-payable.component.ts` to retrieve the boolean values from the service:

```
export class AccountPayableComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private accountPayableService: AccountPayableService,
    private alertService: AlertService
  ) {}

  createFlag = this.accountPayableService.createAccountPayableFlag;
  viewFlag = this.accountPayableService.viewAccountPayableFlag;
```

Lastly, I have these 2 containers in my `account-payable.component.html` that shows depending on the `*ngIf="viewFlag"` and `*ngIf="createFlag`:

```
<div class="container-fluid h-100 d-flex flex-column" *ngIf="createFlag">
    <div class="row flex-fill no-gutters ">
      <div class="col-12 mh-100">
      ...
      </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid h-100 d-flex flex-column" *ngIf="viewFlag ">
    <div class="row flex-fill no-gutters ">
      <div class="col-12 mh-100">
      ...
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is not working and I am seeing this error in my console when I click my menu:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[Boolean]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[Boolean]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for Boolean!
NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[Boolean]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[Boolean]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for Boolean!
    at NullInjector.get (core.js:855)
    at resolveToken (core.js:17513)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:17439)
    at StaticInjector.get (core.js:17265)
    at resolveToken (core.js:17513)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:17439)
    at StaticInjector.get (core.js:17265)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:30392)
    at NgModuleRef_.get (core.js:31577)
    at injectInjectorOnly (core.js:734)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:797)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:754)
    at zone-evergreen.js:858
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:391)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:39679)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:390)
    at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:168)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone-evergreen.js:559)
```

May I know what went wrong? I don't quite understand where the NullInjector is coming from. I'm using angular 8.

This is my `app.component.html`:

```
  <div class="row flex-fill no-gutters my-content" style="min-height: 0;">

    <!-- Side menu -->
    <div class="col-2 mh-100" *ngIf="currentUser">
      <app-side-menu></app-side-menu>
    </div>

    <!-- Content -->
    <div class="col-10 mh-100">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>

  </div>
```

My `app-routing.module.ts`:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent },
  { path: 'account-payable', component: AccountPayableComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
  // otherwise redirect to home
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
];
```

Comment: Are they have same parent?

Comment: Yes, both ```SideMenuComponent``` and ```AccountPayableComponent``` have been declared in my ```app.module.ts```.

Comment: No no, I mean where you use them, they have same parent component or not?

Comment: Yes, show the file-structure, so we can help you

Comment: Thanks for responding, I have updated the questions with my ```app.component.html``` and ```app-routing.module.ts``` to show where I'm using ```<app-side-menu>``` and how it is being routed to ```AccountPayableComponent```. Do they help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to inject a property instead of a dependency here:

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class AccountPayableService {
  createAccountPayableFlag = this.createAccountPayableClick;
  viewAccountPayableFlag = this.viewAccountPayableClick;

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    public createAccountPayableClick: boolean = false,
    public viewAccountPayableClick: boolean = false
  ) {}

}
```

Hence the error.

Change that to this:

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class AccountPayableService {
  createAccountPayableFlag: boolean;
  viewAccountPayableFlag: boolean;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.createAccountPayableClick = false;
    this.viewAccountPayableClick = false;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `side-menu.component.ts` doesn't seem to inject `AccountPayalableService` in the constructor. But defined the service as type for a class property.

```js
export class SideMenuComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private accountPayableService: AccountPayableService;) {}

  // remaining code continues
}
```

**Update:**

You should combine the above change with the answer by @SiddAjmera to make it work.

Comment: I removed ```accountPayableService: AccountPayableService;``` and added ```private accountPayableService: AccountPayableService``` to my side-menu constructor. However, I'm seeing ```ERROR NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[Boolean]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[Boolean]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for Boolean!```